# java try and catch..infinite loop

Tags: java, arraylist, exception

I am having a problem with `try` and `catch`. My program is to insert three different strings name, address and phone number then I convert these three in to a single String using `toString` method.

I have problem with exception handling whenever I write a wrong choice (String or other data type) then catch works infinity times.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class mainClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> arraylist= new ArrayList<String>();
    CreateFormat FormatObject = new CreateFormat();

    int choice;
    String phoneNumber;
    String name,address;
    String format="Empty";
    int x=1;
    int flag=0;
    do
    {
    try

    {   
    System.out.println("Enter your choice");
    System.out.printf("1:Enter new data\n2:Display data");
    choice=input.nextInt();
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
    {
        System.out.println("Enter name  ");
        name=input.next();
        System.out.println("Enter phone number");
        phoneNumber=input.next();
        System.out.println("Enter address");
        address=input.next();
        format=FormatObject.toString(phoneNumber, name, address);
        arraylist.add(format);
        flag++;


    }
        break;
    case 2:
    {
        System.out.println("Name   Phone number   Address");
        System.out.println();
        for(int i=0;i<flag;i++)
        {   
        System.out.println(arraylist.get(i));

        }
    }
        break;
    }

}

 catch(Exception InputMismatchException){
System.out.println("Enter right choice");`
   }while(x==1);
}
}


//The format class ...//returns format for string
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `try` and `catch` are not related to a loop, nor to your problem.

```
while(x==1)
```

is what you test on, yet you never change the value of `x`, so it will always remain 1, and thus the above check will always return true.

Comment: how can i escape catch ? and then return to try...in the while loop

Comment: The problem you have is not to return to try (because that's what your loop does), the problem is that you never leave that loop of yours. There must be a state where `x==1` is `false`.

Comment: @SarmadAijaz since you are the only one who has access to it's requirements: probably, but not guaranteed correctly

Comment: @Stultuske is it wise to update X value in catch block and have check based on it ?

Comment: @unknown at the moment, no matter what he does, he has an infinite loop. the x should be updated as last element of the try block, not in the catch, since when an exception occurs, I assume he wants to repeat the steps

Comment: @Stultuske will you please add code snippet to your answer, sorry for a burden.

Comment: @unknown x = 1; will do it.

Comment: @Stultuske its always been 1 then where to change X value?

Comment: @unknown if you never change it: when do you think (x==1) will return false?
Never. meaning, you will never get out of that loop. I meant: x = -1; it was a typo

Answer (score 0):

I think I now know what your problem actually is.

Simply adding `input.nextLine()` at the very beginning at your code will stop the input running havoc.

```
boolean wrongInput = false;
do {
   try {
       if (wrongInput) {
          input.nextLine();
          wrongInput = false;   
       }
       System.out.println("Enter your choice");
       [...]
   } catch (...) {
       wrongInput = true;
   }
```

should do the trick. However, please note that I noticed two errors in your program (which might be because I do not have the `CreateFormat` class of yours), (a) I cannot add a number to the address and (b) there is no option to stop the loop (which I strongly recommend - where you simply set x = -1 or something similar, better use a `boolean` to end the loop though).

Comment: x==1 => this is a boolean. the naming convention might be clearer, but for all we know, there are different values to be taken into account for x later on, not just true or false

Comment: i did integer.parsInt(input.next());